# How to clear content, but the Formulas not working, despite the presence of constants there (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried all sorts of possible solutions I could find on the internet, but...

The intent is to clear the content and keep the formulas.
The range below does have formulas resulting in values (texts), but it I keep getting the No cells were found error.
I know I can handle it with "On Error Resume Next" and "On Error GoTo 0", but the range is not getting cleared

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A5:F5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
```

Please shed a light to the issue.

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to delete? This method will not clear any cell that has a formula in it. So if all six cells contain a formula (no matter the result of the formula), the error will occur.

Comment: Hi, @VBasic2008 The intent is to clear these cells' calculated values and leave the formula intact. Puzzling to me. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the exact formulas?

Comment: =G5&H5&K5&N5 , =VLOOKUP(G5;CAD!P:Q;2;0), etc

Comment: "The intent is to clear these cells' calculated values and leave the formula intact" - that's not really how Excel works though. If you have a formula it will calculate.  Maybe you can explain why you want to do that.

Comment: Wrap the current formula in an IfError(formula,"")